# Get slug from current url

Tags: php

I have URLs like so:

```
http://localhost/hi-every-body/
http://s1.localhost/hello-world/
http://s2.localhost/bye-world/
```

I want the page "slug" from the URLS, eg.

```
hi-every-body
hello-world
bye-world
```

What's a simple way of doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do exactly that:

```php
trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

It takes the path and strips the forward slashes on both sides.

To get only the last part of the path:

```php
basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Comment: It gets the *whole path*, **not just the ending slug** from `http://example.com/one/two?t=1` you would get `one/two`. In such cases use `basename()` on top of that - "`Returns trailing name component of path`"

Comment: @jave.web added an example for that

Comment: what is url here? The var is empty for me!

Comment: @Gediminas that seems unrelated to this answer, because it assumes that you already have a variable populated with a url.

Comment: use `$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Answer (score 2):

A possibly more robust solution is this:

```
$slugs = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

This will give you an array filled with every element in your URL.

Eg. `http://localhost/one/hippo/cake?t=21`

Becomes the array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => one 
   [1] => hippo 
   [2] => cake 
)
```

This allows you to use each element as you require.

Comment: @ScottM.Stolz Thanks for making me aware! I must have cut and pasted the wrong code without noticing. Doh!